# ld: library not found for -lIOKit.A clang xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I included libIOKit.A.dylib library to my Xcode project using Target section of the project as shown in the below image. The project was built and worked fine and I'm getting some wired error in the compiling state saying

> ld: library not found for -lIOKit.A clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone help me on this matter?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The private framework IOKit built for the Simulator doesn’t exist, so it won’t work there. This library just work on iPad or iPhone.